# npm package.json with two registries

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependency-management

I have project with npm modules from the pubic `https://registry.npmjs.org/` and from my private registry from `https://npm.fury.io` how can I setup my `~/.npmrc` or other npm config so i can have something like this in my package.json

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.2.3",
    "myPrivateLibFromNpmFury": "0.0.4"
  }
}
```

*edit*: the best way is maybe to have both registries inside the package.json, ruby does it like this with Gemfile, if you have a private gem just add it's registry at the top of the file. Otherwise if would hide this registry in my `~/.npmrc` other programmers will not be able to run `npm install`

Comment: have you tried this: `npm --registry https://npm.fury.io` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's explained here : https://gemfury.com/l/private-npm

> How it Works Once you upload your private modules to your Gemfury
>   account, you can install them anywhere using command line:
>
> ```
> npm install my-module --registry https://npm.fury.io/452f6E403CDph10714e41/me/
> ```
>
> Or switch your .npmrc to our smart proxy which seamlessly blends your
>   Gemfury repo with the public npm registry:
>
> ```
> registry = https://npm-proxy.fury.io/452f6E403CDph10714e41/me/
> ```
>
> You're always ready to seamlessly npm install your private and public
>   modules from Gemfury.

To resume, they say you use they registry, and it match automatically with the npm public registry for the npm modules.